# Asking for npt with live555 server

Tags: rtsp, live555

I'm writing an rtsp client, and I'm having troubles figuring out the current playtime of the media I'm streaming.

In the rtsp procotol, it's said that sending a play request without a range should result by getting the current position in the reply with the unit from the request, but i'm getting nothing except RTP-info.

I tried with "Range: npt=" and "Range: npt=-" without success.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get the current time by looking at the RTP header. The RTP header has a time stamp. Diving this time stamp by Sample rate will give you the current time. Sample rate is given in the Session Description Protocol (usually is 90000)